# Conjure-up/JuJu failed to bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, conjure-up

I'm attempting to set up a openstack cluster using MaaS and Conjure-up. I was able to get all the way to deploying the stack using conjure-up. Yet when it goes to deploy the cloud, I can see in the MaaS web GUI that its deploying Ubuntu 16.04 but it hangs then errors out I get the following in the log.

```
2018-11-06 19:58:17,300 [ERROR] conjure-up/openstack-base - common.py:60 - Error bootstrapping controller: ['Creating Juju controller "conjure-up-cloud-maas-e9a-ac6" on cloud-maas-e9a', 'Looking for packaged Juju agent version 2.4.3 for amd64', 'Launching controller instance(s) on cloud-maas-e9a...', ' - stnakn (arch=amd64 mem=36G cores=24)', 'Installing Juju agent on bootstrap instance', 'Fetching Juju GUI 2.14.0', 'ERROR failed to bootstrap model: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "stnakn" is started but not deployed']
2018-11-06 19:58:17,302 [DEBUG] conjure-up/openstack-base - events.py:52 - Setting Error at conjureup/events.py:149
2018-11-06 19:58:17,315 [ERROR] conjure-up/openstack-base - events.py:161 - Unhandled exception in <Task finished coro=<BaseBootstrapController.run() done, defined at /snap/conjure-up/1031/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py:15> exception=BootstrapError('Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: maas)',)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1031/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py", line 21, in run
    await self.do_bootstrap()
  File "/snap/conjure-up/1031/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conjureup/controllers/juju/bootstrap/common.py", line 65, in do_bootstrap
    app.provider.cloud_type))
conjureup.errors.BootstrapError: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: maas)
2018-11-06 19:58:17,324 [DEBUG] conjure-up/openstack-base - __init__.py:27 - Showing dialog for exception: Unable to bootstrap (cloud type: maas)
```

I'm somewhat new to this but part of me thinks that this may be due to JuJu reporting version as "2.4.3-bionic-amd64" While in the error it is looking for "2.4.3 amd64" But it does seem to proceed. Also due to the age of the servers I'm working with they have iLO3 and I have to set them to manual power. I thought it was still possible to use this set up with manual power am I incorrect?

Thank you in advance for any insight. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello again, so I got past this error I experienced above. I was able to successfully set up iLO3 so conjure-up can automatically power the servers on and off. I even got  further with the deployment! JuJu got all the servers set up with Ubuntu but when it started to set up the Openstack services, I get Blocked on the Ceph services, then the whole deployment failed.

Comment: Found that blocked was due to incomplete relations. But also something is jacked in this deployment. I keep running into registered bugs that are at least a couple years old that are "fixed" or marked now as invalid. LIke this one https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1727355

Comment: and this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1767137

Comment: MaaS with Juju is just too buggy. Plus I'm starting to think the issues' I've experienced are due to wanting me to pay for support since answers on these forums are few and far between. Thanks for the lack of help!! Yay community! Long live social skills like Torvalds am I rite!! /s bet this gets answers now lol.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I noted when I installed recently was that even though it deploys openstack on 18.04, it still needs an 16.04 image in order to launch an use juju.  This is not the case if you just use juju (juju uses 18.04) and not conjure-up.

Update: just tried to install again (dec 31, 18) and now it is using 18.04 like it should.

Comment: `$ juju bootstrap --bootstrap-series=bionic`



start `conjure-up` select software to deploy and then you will be asked if you want to create new controller or use existing one. Select the controller created in step 1 and continue.